# Python/Pandas - df.duplicated() MemoryError: cannot allocate memory for array

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, memory

I am getting a `MemoryError: cannot allocate memory for array` when using `df.duplicated()` to check for duplicates in a data frame in Python 3.6.4.

The df has about 150,000 rows and 208 columns and there are no issues with loading the data into a df (using chunks per below).

```
myList = []
for chunks in pd.read_csv(filename, header=0, low_memory=False, chunksize=20000):
        myList.append(chunks)

dfMain = pd.concat(myList, axis=0)
dfMain.index.name = 'Index'

print (dfMain.shape)
Out: (151982, 208)
```

Everything is fine up until this point.

```
   #Marks duplicated rows with TRUE or FALSE and put into a new df
    dfDup1 = pd.DataFrame(dfMain.duplicated(keep=False)) #set to False to view all duplicates
```

This is where the error occurs: `MemoryError: cannot allocate memory for array` and the script stops.

Unfortunately, reducing the number of columns is not an option, I need to check for duplicates across all of variables (although I did drop 150 variables to test but the problem persisted). And I do need to export the duplicated values to df/csv, so can't use `drop_duplicates()` at this stage.

The computer has plenty of RAM (64 gigs), but Python/pandas is using only a fraction of it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked whether there's enough memory to make a copy of the df? (I assume there _should_ be, but this could rule out some not-too-likely but easy-to-fix problems, like "oops, I'm running a 32-bit Python".)

Comment: @abarnert - plenty of hard drive space, but just checked - this computer is running 32-bit Python. Computer was reformatted a couple of weeks ago and somehow ended up with a 32-bit version. Easy-to-fix and overlook! Thanks, will install 64-bit and try again.

Comment: Hah, that's why I always test the dumb things that couldn't possibly be wrong unless I'm an idiot—because half the time, I'm an idiot. :)

Comment: (Also, I noticed that your df seems like it should take right around 2GB, which wouldn't be a problem with 64GB of RAM… except that 32-bit Python can only access somewhere between 2-4GB of that RAM.)

Comment: Thanks again, abrnert! Just reinstalled 64-bit, working like a charm.

Comment: If you think other people might run into this problem and benefit from the same solution, you should write and accept an answer. If not, close or delete your question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was use of Python 32-bit instead of 64-bit. Thanks to abrnert for helping resolve this.